# Ductless 1/2 Bath Vent - yes or no?

Tags: bathroom, vent, exhaust-fan

From what I can understand, code says any bath fan needs to be vented to the outside. I live in Denver, CO and have been told that I can use just a charcoal ductless fan in the half bath we are putting into our basement because it doesn't have a shower/tub. What is correct?

Comment: Will the bath have a window? Without a window you do need a vent to get the moisture out. Yes a ductless mini can be set up in a dry mode basically a dehumidifier. I believe a live fan while using the shower will be better for the structure and still may be required but not sure about your jurisdiction.

Comment: I wonder how the fan industry can sell "ductless" bathroom vent fans and square that up against building codes requiring venting. Is the target market just for people who are willing to ignore the codes?

Comment: No, the bathroom won't have a window. Unfortunately it aligns to our patio's foundation. So a duct would have to be probably longer than ideal to reach the outside. The bathroom won't have a shower. Just toilet and sink.

Comment: The duct would also need to run straight, then jog down under the joist and then head up and outside. Would the down and up duct be an issue in this situation with the limited moisture in the bathroom, since it doesn't have a shower?